# backtracking-program collapses at runtime

Tags: c, backtracking

guys! i have an embarrassing problem. I tried to solve a problem using backtracking and it does not work. The task: Given a matrix with n x m elements and considering that every element represents a height on a map, i must get from the initial position(x1, y1) to the final position(x2,y2) only by moving from a higher point to a lower one. 
This is the code. But it collapses at runtime. Can you help me? I would be more than grateful. :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10
int h[MAX][MAX], x;
int x1, x2, y1, y2;


typedef struct pozitie{
int x;
int y;
}pozitie;
pozitie sol[50];

int xd[4]={-1,0,0,1}; //motion coordinates
int yd[4]={0,-1,1,0};


void afisare_matrice(int n, int m){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        printf("%d ", h[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}

}

int valid(int niv, int c1, int c2){
if(h[sol[niv-1].x][sol[niv-1].y]>=h[c1][c2] && niv>0)
    return 1;
return 0;
}

int solutie(int c1, int c2){  //check if it is solution
if (c1==x2 && c2==y2)
    return 1;
return 0;
}

void afisare(int niv){  //print the solution
int i;
for(i=0;i<=niv;i++)
    printf("(%d, %d)  ", sol[i].x, sol[i].y);
printf("\n");
}

void back(int niv){
int posib, c1,c2;
for(posib=0;posib<4;posib++){
    c1=sol[niv-1].x + xd[posib];  //fixing new coordinates
    c2=sol[niv-1].y + yd[posib];
    if(valid(niv,c1,c2)){    //test if they are valid
        if(solutie(c1,c2))      //if they are the coordinates of the final point
            afisare(niv);       //print the solution
        else back(niv+1);
    }
}


}





int main(){
FILE *f;
f=fopen("harta.txt", "rt");
if(!f){
    printf("Eroare la deschiderea fisierului!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int n,m;int i,j;
fscanf(f, "%d%d", &n,&m);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
         fscanf(f, "%d", &h[i][j]);


    }                                     /*reading the matrix from file*/


afisare_matrice(n,m);  //print matrix on screen
x1=1;
y1=1;    //coordinates of initial position
x2=4;
y2=2;    //coordinates of final position

sol[0].x=x1;        //set the starting point in the first position of solution
sol[0].y=y1;

back(1);

fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'collapses'? Do you get errors?

Comment: Your `valid` function should enforce that the new coordinates `c1` and ´c2` lie within the matrix before accessing `h[c1][c2]`.

Comment: no. a window pops up and says that the program stopped working

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem :) Hope you have a nice day!

Comment: What is your operating system? what IDE and compiler do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium, CodeBlocks